# How to take a data from .dat files without empty columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm new in pandas and python. I have a problem that I don't understand, I have a set of .dat files, so I collect them in one .csv file.

```
path =r'/Users/Desktop/03/17'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*dat")

dfs = []
for filename in filenames:
dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

data_day = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)    
data_day.head()
data_day.to_csv('/Users/Desktop/11.csv',index=False)
data2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/Desktop/11.csv', sep=' ')

data1 = data2.dropna(axis=1)
data1
```

It works good with this type of .dat files wich contain 21 columns.
[21 columns](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Ezz7E7dYvEVVpjd21oaE5SR2s/view?usp=sharing)
But doesn't work with this type of files with contain 27 columns.
[27 columns](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Ezz7E7dYvEV3BjbTZ6N3BhR28/view?usp=sharing)
Instead of 27 columns it makes files with 18 columns.
What is my mistake?

Comment: Try this: `data2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/Desktop/11.csv', sep='\s+')`, not sure if your first `read_csv` is reading exactly, but your dat files have more than a single space as a separator

Comment: Also it looks like you dat files are fixed width files so you could try `data2 = pd.read_fwf('/Users/Desktop/11.csv')` and also change this line `dfs.append(pd.read_fwf(filename))`

Comment: now, when I try to read this csv - separator ',' doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separator in your linked files isn't a single space, so `pd.read_csv(..., sep=' ')` is failing. Try `pd.read_csv(..., delim_whitespace=True)` to use any amount of whitespace as a separator. This should be roughly equivalent to `pd.read_csv(..., sep='\s+')`, but faster.

Comment: No problem is not in separator, it is showing 95982 rows × 18 columns again

Comment: That's strange, as it worked on the files you posted: 
`In [33]: pd.read_csv("CFKADS2104-20140317-070553Z-DataLog_User.dat", delim_whitespace=True).shape
Out[33]: (3331, 27)`. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Again, strange. That's the same version I am using. I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: Yep, that's what I pasted above. I got 27 columns when reading `CFKADS2104-20140317-070553Z-DataLog_User.dat`.

Comment: I reload Python and "\s+" "delim_whitespace=True' are good working, sorry for wasting your time and thanks for the help!

Comment: Not a waste at all, glad I could help.